# Search form escaping characters and spaces?

Tags: 7, search, .htaccess

Drupal 7.

I'm thinking it must be in the htaccess file, as I just went live, and suddenly if I search for something like "two words" it ends up searching for "two%20words" and obviously I get no results.

Same goes for quotes, etc.  Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know you are searching for *two%20words*? `%20` is the percent-encoded value for the space character as mandated by [RFC 3986](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986), so it is absolutely correct that this value appears in the address bar of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

That wasn't entirely it - it was escaping with a %25 and passing it to the search form, causing no results.  It was an issue with my htaccess, it's fixed.